# Windows Defender is active even when explicitly disabled

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

So, I've disabled Windows Defender on my Windows 10 Home machine, here is how it looks in the settings:
[image]

However, I've noticed that when I download files in Chrome, it still scans them anyway. I've noticed this because downloads of certain file types took a lot of time (even minutes in some cases) to actually complete after reaching 100% download progress, and during that time the MsMpEng.exe process is saturating one of the CPU cores, like you see in this screenshot:
[image]

Is there a way to actually disable these scans? I work as a developer and it extremely infuriating having to wait 3-4 minutes of extra time every time I download a JAR file.

Comment: tbh, you really need to be on Pro if you're a pro. Win Home makes this type of task really difficult, to stop regular users from figuring out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the downloads folder as an exclusion and see if that helps.
Go to `Settings`, `Virus & threat protection`, `Virus & threat protection settings`, and then click `Exclusions`.

[image]

Else, there's a few Windows Defender related services (I've got 5 of them on my computer) which you can disable - you might need additional permissions in the registry to do that.

To find the start parameters of services in Registry, go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\your_service`.
You will find the service's name in `Services`, after right-clicking `Properties`.
The parameter is named `Start` and accepts values from 1 to 4 I believe. 4 stands for "disabled".
`mpssvc` won't allow you to change the values there, so you should right-click on the mspsvc folder inside Regedit and assign yourself the necessary permissions - if that does not work, you need to use a tool like [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/) to bypass that.

[image]

There's also 2 hardcore solutions:

1. Uninstall Windows Defender through powershell with `Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name Windows-Defender` (Windows Server only)
2. Uninstall Windows Defender in the windows installation image through DISM or some third-party software

Comment: I should've specified, this is a Windows 10 Home installation, I don't think `Uninstall-WindowsFeature` is available in this edition (powershell doesn't recognize it)

Comment: My bad - that command only works on Windows Servers. Did you try adding your downloads folder as an exception?

Comment: Well, with Windows Defender disabled (like in my first screenshot) it doesn't let me add exclusions. I guess I could turn it back on and then use exclusions, but it seems insane that I cannot just disable it altogether.

Comment: I've updated my answer with instructions to disable the services via regedit.

Comment: Setting the type to 4 worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to disable it from gpedit?
first need to disable tamper protection to avoid init Windows Defender again on reboot

Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Virus & threat protection settings > Manage settings > Tamper Protection > switch OFF

Then run gpedit.msc

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus > (Double-click) Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus > select ENABLED.
Apply, Ok and restart computer. This should turn off these Windows Defender

Comment: gpedit isn't enabled on Win Home by default. You need a hack to enable it - https://www.ghacks.net/2019/01/07/how-to-enable-gpedit-msc-group-policy-on-windows-10-home-devices/